# MultiUserChatException$NotAMucServiceException: Can not join ... , because 'localhost' does not provide a MUC (XEP-45) service

Tags: android, ejabberd, smack

Component using:
  **ejabberd- 18.06** and **SMACK-4.2.4**

I have installed **Spark** ejabberd client in my PC and there I can create chat room. But When I rum the below code it get the below exception. I tried on Android emulator and phone also, connected on same local network.

**SMACK ERROR:**

```
W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChatException$NotAMucServiceException: Can not join 'mamun@localhost', because 'localhost' does not provide a MUC (XEP-45) service.
                  at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.enter(MultiUserChat.java:314)
W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.createOrJoin(MultiUserChat.java:498)
                  at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.createOrJoin(MultiUserChat.java:444)
                  at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.create(MultiUserChat.java:419)
                  at time.friends.myapplication.GroupChat$1.onClick(GroupChat.java:58)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**SMACK Source:**

```
MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(
        SessionHolder.abstractXMPPConnection);
 MultiUserChat muc = manager.getMultiUserChat(
        getEntityBareJid(SessionHolder.abstractXMPPConnection.getUser()+""));
    Log.e("Group","Group created successfully");
 try {

    muc.create(getResourcepart(grp.getText()+"")).makeInstant();

 } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (MultiUserChatException.MucAlreadyJoinedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (MultiUserChatException.MissingMucCreationAcknowledgeException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (MultiUserChatException.NotAMucServiceException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Here **manager.isServiceEnabled** return true.

**ejabberd Configaretion:**

```
     hosts:
   - "localhost"
 ....
 access_rules:
   ## This rule allows access only for local users:
   ##local:
   ##  - allow: local
   ## Only non-blocked users can use c2s connections:
   c2s:
     - deny: blocked
     - allow
   ## Only admins can send announcement messages:
   announce:
     - allow: admin
   ## Only admins can use the configuration interface:
   configure:
     - allow: admin
   ## Only accounts of the local ejabberd server can create rooms:
   muc_create:
     - allow: all

 ....
 modules:
   ....
   mod_muc:
     ## host: "conference.localhost"
     access: all
     access_admin: muc_admin
     access_create: all
     access_persistent: muc_create
   ##   default_room_options:
   ##     allow_subscription: true
   ## mod_muc_admin: {}
   ## mod_muc_log: {}
   ## mod_multicast: {}
```

I have also tried **host: "conference.localhost"** and **host: "conference.@HOST@"** uncommenting this.

**ejabberd log:**

```
     #iq{id = <<"Z4XNM-14">>,type = get,lang = <<"en">>,
     from = #jid{user = <<"mamun">>,server = <<"localhost">>,
                 resource = <<"6215854561312688131227">>,luser = <<"mamun">>,
                 lserver = <<"localhost">>,
                 lresource = <<"6215854561312688131227">>},
     to = #jid{user = <<>>,server = <<"conference.localhost">>,resource = <<>>,
               luser = <<>>,lserver = <<"conference.localhost">>,
               lresource = <<>>},
     sub_els = [#xmlel{name = <<"query">>,
                       attrs = [{<<"xmlns">>,
                                 <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info">>}],
                       children = []}],
     meta = #{ip => {192,168,1,3}}}
 2018-08-18 23:04:05.198 [debug] <0.550.0>@mod_stream_mgmt:check_h_attribute:480 mamun@localhost/6215854561312688131227 acknowledged 3 of 3 stanzas
 2018-08-18 23:04:05.201 [debug] <0.476.0>@ejabberd_router:do_route:352 route:
 #iq{id = <<"Z4XNM-14">>,type = result,lang = <<"en">>,
     from =
         #jid{
             user = <<>>,server = <<"conference.localhost">>,resource = <<>>,
             luser = <<>>,lserver = <<"conference.localhost">>,
             lresource = <<>>},
     to =
         #jid{
             user = <<"mamun">>,server = <<"localhost">>,
             resource = <<"6215854561312688131227">>,luser = <<"mamun">>,
             lserver = <<"localhost">>,
             lresource = <<"6215854561312688131227">>},
     sub_els =
         [#disco_info{
              node = <<>>,
              identities =
                  [#identity{
                       category = <<"conference">>,type = <<"text">>,
                       lang = <<>>,name = <<"Chatrooms">>}],
              features =
                  [<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info">>,
                   <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items">>,
                   <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc">>,<<"vcard-temp">>,
                   <<"urn:xmpp:mucsub:0">>,
                   <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#unique">>,
                   <<"jabber:iq:register">>,
                   <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm">>,<<"urn:xmpp:mam:tmp">>,
                   <<"urn:xmpp:mam:0">>,<<"urn:xmpp:mam:1">>,
                   <<"urn:xmpp:mam:2">>],
              xdata =
                  [#xdata{
                       type = result,instructions = [],title = undefined,
                       reported = undefined,items = [],
                       fields =
                           [#xdata_field{
                                label = <<>>,type = hidden,
                                var = <<"FORM_TYPE">>,required = false,
                                desc = <<>>,
                                values =
                                    [<<"http://jabber.org/network/serverinfo">>],
                                options = [],sub_els = []}]}]}],
     meta = #{ip => {192,168,1,3}}}
 2018-08-18 23:04:05.204 [debug] <0.476.0>@ejabberd_local:do_route:141 local route:
 #iq{id = <<"Z4XNM-14">>,type = result,lang = <<"en">>,
     from =
         #jid{
             user = <<>>,server = <<"conference.localhost">>,resource = <<>>,
             luser = <<>>,lserver = <<"conference.localhost">>,
             lresource = <<>>},
     to =
         #jid{
             user = <<"mamun">>,server = <<"localhost">>,
             resource = <<"6215854561312688131227">>,luser = <<"mamun">>,
             lserver = <<"localhost">>,
             lresource = <<"6215854561312688131227">>},
     sub_els =
         [#disco_info{
              node = <<>>,
              identities =
                  [#identity{
                       category = <<"conference">>,type = <<"text">>,
                       lang = <<>>,name = <<"Chatrooms">>}],
              features =
                  [<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info">>,
                   <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items">>,
                   <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc">>,<<"vcard-temp">>,
                   <<"urn:xmpp:mucsub:0">>,
                   <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#unique">>,
                   <<"jabber:iq:register">>,
                   <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm">>,<<"urn:xmpp:mam:tmp">>,
                   <<"urn:xmpp:mam:0">>,<<"urn:xmpp:mam:1">>,
                   <<"urn:xmpp:mam:2">>],
              xdata =
                  [#xdata{
                       type = result,instructions = [],title = undefined,
                       reported = undefined,items = [],
                       fields =
                           [#xdata_field{
                                label = <<>>,type = hidden,
                                var = <<"FORM_TYPE">>,required = false,
                                desc = <<>>,
                                values =
                                    [<<"http://jabber.org/network/serverinfo">>],
                                options = [],sub_els = []}]}]}],
     meta = #{ip => {192,168,1,3}}}
 2018-08-18 23:04:05.207 [debug] <0.476.0>@ejabberd_sm:do_route:651 processing packet to full JID:
 #iq{id = <<"Z4XNM-14">>,type = result,lang = <<"en">>,
     from =
         #jid{
             user = <<>>,server = <<"conference.localhost">>,resource = <<>>,
             luser = <<>>,lserver = <<"conference.localhost">>,
             lresource = <<>>},
     to =
         #jid{
             user = <<"mamun">>,server = <<"localhost">>,
             resource = <<"6215854561312688131227">>,luser = <<"mamun">>,
             lserver = <<"localhost">>,
             lresource = <<"6215854561312688131227">>},
     sub_els =
         [#disco_info{
              node = <<>>,
              identities =
                  [#identity{
                       category = <<"conference">>,type = <<"text">>,
                       lang = <<>>,name = <<"Chatrooms">>}],
              features =
                  [<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info">>,
                   <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items">>,
                   <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc">>,<<"vcard-temp">>,
                   <<"urn:xmpp:mucsub:0">>,
                   <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#unique">>,
                   <<"jabber:iq:register">>,
                   <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm">>,<<"urn:xmpp:mam:tmp">>,
                   <<"urn:xmpp:mam:0">>,<<"urn:xmpp:mam:1">>,
                   <<"urn:xmpp:mam:2">>],
              xdata =
                  [#xdata{
                       type = result,instructions = [],title = undefined,
                       reported = undefined,items = [],
                       fields =
                           [#xdata_field{
                                label = <<>>,type = hidden,
                                var = <<"FORM_TYPE">>,required = false,
                                desc = <<>>,
                                values =
                                    [<<"http://jabber.org/network/serverinfo">>],
                                options = [],sub_els = []}]}]}],
     meta = #{ip => {192,168,1,3}}}
 2018-08-18 23:04:05.210 [debug] <0.476.0>@ejabberd_sm:do_route:675 sending to process <0.550.0>:
 #iq{id = <<"Z4XNM-14">>,type = result,lang = <<"en">>,
     from =
         #jid{
             user = <<>>,server = <<"conference.localhost">>,resource = <<>>,
             luser = <<>>,lserver = <<"conference.localhost">>,
             lresource = <<>>},
     to =
         #jid{
             user = <<"mamun">>,server = <<"localhost">>,
             resource = <<"6215854561312688131227">>,luser = <<"mamun">>,
             lserver = <<"localhost">>,
             lresource = <<"6215854561312688131227">>},
     sub_els =
         [#disco_info{
              node = <<>>,
              identities =
                  [#identity{
                       category = <<"conference">>,type = <<"text">>,
                       lang = <<>>,name = <<"Chatrooms">>}],
              features =
                  [<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info">>,
                   <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items">>,
                   <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc">>,<<"vcard-temp">>,
                   <<"urn:xmpp:mucsub:0">>,
                   <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#unique">>,
                   <<"jabber:iq:register">>,
                   <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm">>,<<"urn:xmpp:mam:tmp">>,
                   <<"urn:xmpp:mam:0">>,<<"urn:xmpp:mam:1">>,
                   <<"urn:xmpp:mam:2">>],
              xdata =
                  [#xdata{
                       type = result,instructions = [],title = undefined,
                       reported = undefined,items = [],
                       fields =
                           [#xdata_field{
                                label = <<>>,type = hidden,
                                var = <<"FORM_TYPE">>,required = false,
                                desc = <<>>,
                                values =
                                    [<<"http://jabber.org/network/serverinfo">>],
                                options = [],sub_els = []}]}]}],
     meta = #{ip => {192,168,1,3}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the problem was -

```
**MultiUserChat muc = manager.getMultiUserChat(
    getEntityBareJid(SessionHolder.abstractXMPPConnection.getUser()+""));**
```

the parameter name format should

> **Group_Name@conference.HOST_NAME**

i.e-myroom@conference.localhost

This works for me. :)